# Design-pattern: different types of objects to one

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I want to convert different types of objects into one.

For example I have:
Object1:class1
Object2:class2
Object3:class3

All objects are different, I could not make them to inherit one interface.

Before transferring to another part of application, I want to convert them to ObjectDTO:ClassDTO.

What design pattern could be used in this situation?

Comment: Give us some problem to solve. You having 3 class is not a problem. Please explain what you wanted to do but you cant? adding some code will help.

Comment: I can to do it, that is why there is no code. But I ask for some pattern that could be used in case when you need to convert different types of objects into one object type.

Comment: You have given no context to answer. Be specific in what you want to convert? What those `Object1`, `Object2` have? and what `ObjectDTO` have? are those properties virtual in `ObjectDTO`?

Comment: Is it a one-off exercise?  Or do you have to do it in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `implicit` type conversion operator in C#:

```
public class Object1DTO 
{
    public int Property {get; set;}
}

public class Object1 
{
    public int Property {get; set;}

    public static implicit operator Object1DTO(Object1 object1)
    {
        return new Object1DTO { Property = object1.Property };
    }
}
```

Or you can also use extensions:

```
public static class Extensions 
{
    public static Object1DTO ToDTO(this Object1 object1)
    {
        return new Object1DTO { Property = object1.Property };
    }
}
```

You can also look at libraries like [`automapper`](http://automapper.org/) to handle such object-object mapping scenarios.

Comment: Good idea, but I also need to use it for sealed classes. (In your example: Object1 is sealed and I could not extent it with implicit operator)

Comment: @Anton - You can have it in either of the classes. You can have it in Object1DTO too.

Comment: yes, but DTO should not have any behavior except for storage and retrieval of its own data following its description.

Comment: @Anton - Didn't think of that. Anyways, added one more suggestion on using extensions.